# Should you let the editor of a paper under review know when you post preprints of additional papers that build on the paper under review?

Tags: publications

Let's say that one author has a paper under review, and continues on subsequent works based on the paper under review.

When the author puts preprints of subsequent works available online, should the author let the editor of the first paper know about those subsequent works?

Comment: What are some potential benefits?  Sounds like something an editor would ignore.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I can relate to this situation. For example, in the paper under review you might be arguing about a gap in the literature that may no longer be true if you include the papers that build on the paper under review. Other times, you might be re-using data, where the first use is in the paper under review and follow-up analyses are in subsequent papers. Things can get a bit awkward when the date of writing the papers gets out of sync with when they are accepted.

Comment: You could check this publication on [Maximizing Your Data or Data Slicing? Recommendations for Managing Multiple Submissions from the Same Dataset](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1740-8784.2011.00228.x/references), it might help.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no need to do this.

If you submit a work to a journal you submit it as is and related to the current state of the art at time of submission. Things that happen after submission should in general not interfere with the current submission. While it could be in some exceptional cases that events after submission may influence the perception of the article, in general the article should be processed with respect to the date of submission.

If I imagine that people would start sending any kind of "additional information" after an article has been submitted, I would expect that this could lead to a great mess (articles submitted which are in fact only preliminary, additional appendices added at a later stage, corrections/amendments…). So I would guess that an editor would generally ignore the additional information and even may find this a bit strange.

However, you may add additional information in case of a revision/resubmission and this is the right time to add anything that could be relevant (with the only exception of severe error in your work - if you find one inform the editor immediately).

Answer (score 0):

That's a somewhat tough question to answer (though a good problem to have!).

It depends on the journal you submitted it to's policy on the subject. The biggest issue will be if some of the work you're publishing elsewhere will be required by the reviewers for the current project. You can find yourself in a sticky situation.

For instance, let's say they want you to do an experiment or report on data that you were planning to publish elsewhere...that data hasn't yet been published so you can't include a reference to it yet, but if you include it in your currently submitted paper during the rewrite/resubmission, then you can't submit it as new work.

Also many journals won't accept the newer manuscripts for review until you've published the reviewed work on which it was based.

Each situation is unique. Best thing to do is just ask the editor.